# SQLException Column not found

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

Maybe it's a stupid question but I really tried to solve the problem without succes, I have a methode called `StockNivSens` as follows :

```
public void StockNivSens(){
    int nbrRoles = getNbrRoles();
    String objID;
    int sumPerm = 0, pName = 0;
    String sql = "SELECT objectdwID, peName "
            + "FROM permissiondw pdw, securityrole sr "
            + "WHERE pdw.securityPropertyID = sr.securityPropertyID "
            + "AND pdw.RoleID = sr.RoleID";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        res = pst.executeQuery();
        while(res.next()){
            objID = res.getString("objectdwID").toString();
            pName = Integer.parseInt(res.getString("peName"));
            ....
```

When I excute it, it gives me an `SQLException` error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'peName' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:862)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1076)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5206)
    at com.GRoles.NiveauDeSensibilite.StockNivSens(NiveauDeSensibilite.java:732)
    at com.GRoles.NiveauDeSensibilite.<init>(NiveauDeSensibilite.java:282)
    at com.GRoles.NiveauDeSensibilite$1.run(NiveauDeSensibilite.java:77)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But it works when I execute it th Mysql Workbench :

[image]

Maybe the parsing is the cause of the error, but I need the variable `pName` in *int* format (it's a *VARCHAR* in the database)

## Edit 1:

When I added :

```
System.out.println(objID);
System.out.println(pName);
```

It shows me the result.

```
16
3
```

And after that print the error.

## Edit 2:

I replaced the impecit sql with the explicit one :

```
String sql = "select objectdwID, peName "
                + "from permissiondw pdw inner join securityrole sr "
                + "WHERE pdw.securityPropertyID = sr.securityPropertyID"
                + "AND pdw.RoleID = sr.RoleID";
```

The error still remains.

Comment: Have you tried qualifying it with the table name as you do in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: What does this yield: `System.out.println(res.getMetaData().getColumnName(1));`

Comment: @Actorclavilis, yes I tried it but it didn't work
@Shloim, it returns `objectdwID`

Comment: my quess is you have 2 databases, and you are using the wrong one

Comment: As @Actorclavilis says, you are doing a old style join, not an explicit one, and you are not qualifying the table alias. The engine maybe we looking into the the wrong table. Granted it should find it

Comment: @Drew, I think the problem isn't in the join because even if I type only `SELECT objectdwID, peName FROM permissiondw pdw, securityrole sr` it gives me the same error.

Comment: I just don't know why you would want to code like that. Be explicit with the `t1.`   ..... `t2.`  Also do explicit joins moving forward. There are all these db layers involved and in different environments you are leaving it up to chance.

Comment: just debug and check whether your connection object is pointing to correct DB or not. Do table aliasing and project column names with that aliased names.